Resemblance of a child towards mother or father
Often we see that a child resembles more closely towards either the father's facial structure or the mother's facial structure.
I want to know what determines this resemblance and is it possible to not have any resemblance at all? What is the science behind this?
PS : I am not a biology or medical student. Just a curious mind here.

Welcome to Biology SE! Unless you know of any research suggesting otherwise, I would guess that the impression that a child tends to resemble only one parent is just the result of our bias to only notice when that is the case, and not a real phenomenon. If you are curious about the biology of resemblance, I would suggest reading a primer on genetics and inheritance.

Or, to put it another way, I've my dad's nose and my mum's hairy legs, but people generally see the nose first.

@Eonema : Can you please share the link to a primer on genetics and inheritance?

To put it simply, the resemblance is because of genetics (your DNA). You have 23 pairs of chromosomes, or a total of 46 individual chromosomes. Half of those come from your mother, the other half your father. In some cases, you will get the same copy of a gene from both parents, this is called being homozygous. Having two different copies is referred to as being heterozygous. Blood types are the simplest way to explain this, if both parents give you the gene coding for type A, your blood type will be A. If both give you B, then you are B etc. If you get the type A gene form one parent and the type B from the other, then you are type AB.
Now to finally answer your question on why resemblance varies, some genes are dominant and others are recessive. That means that if we suppose a gene for brown eyes (this is much more complicated) is dominant over blue eyes, then a child will always have brown eyes if they inherit the "brown eye gene" from one parent, regardless of wether they get the blue eye gene of the brown eye gene from the other parent.
So if hypothetically one parent has a lot more traits that happen to be dominant, the child will more closely resemble them. But statistically this will typically be more even. If you want to learn more then you need to pick up a high school biology book.
Sources to explain some of this
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5289863/
https://www.hudsonalpha.org/the-genetics-of-eye-color/
